# JS NavSlide not working properly when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked at the other questions that have been answered, tried them out myself and I still couldn't click on my burger and have the slide out menu. I was following a tutorial and it was turning out fine until I got to the JavaScript section of it. I'm not really too sure what I am doing wrong here. Looked around in the forum and tried all the solutions I could find for it to still not work.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.navigation');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  });
}
const app = () => {
  navSlide();
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.townlogo{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

ul.navigation{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 40%;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: (white);
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
ul.navigation li{
    list-style: none;
}
ul.navigation a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
}

li a:hover{
    color: rgb(190 30 45);
}

.indexbody{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    color: rgb(65 57 61);
}

.img1, .img2{
    position: relative;
    opacity:0.70;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed; /*Can be adjusted for mobile viewing*/
}


.img1{
    background-image: url('../Images/lantern.jpg');
    min-height: 600px;
}

.img2{
    background-image: url('../Images/cookingcropped.jpg');
    min-height: 400px;
}

.section{
    text-align: center;
    padding:50px 80px;
}

.section-mission{
    background-color: rgb(65 57 61);
    color:white;
}

.section-vision{
    background-color: rgb(65 57 61);
    color:white;
}

.menutext{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black ;
}

.menutext .border{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 8px;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px black;
    text-decoration: none;
    
}

a.viewmenu:link{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    a.viewmenu:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        }

a.viewmenu:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}

a.viewmenu:active{
    text-decoration: none;
    }

/*rectangle div contains copyright footer section*/
.rectangle{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: athelas, serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 520px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
    border-right: 520px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
    .navigation{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .navigation{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: (white);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .navigation li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }
    }

    .nav-active{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }

    .rectangle{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: athelas, serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 14px;
        border-left: 200px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
        border-right: 200px solid rgb(190 30 45) ;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head> <!--Header containing title,meta,and links-->
        <title>ctowncuisine</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/qsw5hiv.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css"> <!--link reference to CSS stylesheet-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav>
        <div class="townlogo"> <!--Technically the header of the page, but used in the body for consistency-->
            <img src="Images/townlogo.jpg" alt="chinese restaurant logo">
        </div>
            <ul class="navigation"> <!--section for top navigation bar-->
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="order_online.html"><span>Reserve Table</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="burger" id="burger">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
                <div class="line4"></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    

     <div class="indexbody"></div>
        <div class="img1"></div> <!--lantern.html image class-->
        <a class="viewmenu" href="menu.html"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
            <div  class="menutext">
            <span class="border ">
            View Our Menu
            </span>
            </div> 
    </a>
        

<section class="section section-mission">
    <h2 class="mission">Our Mission</h2> <!--This is the second heading containing: Our Mission section-->
    <p>To bring quality, style and the wish for good fortune to all of our guests. We provide a high-end experience through Chinese cuisine.
    </p> <!--Paragraph containing the mission statement of TOWN-->
</section>

<div class="img2"> <!--div classifying second image: cookingcropped.html-->
    <span class="border">
    </span>
</div>

<section class="section section-vision">
    <h2 class="vision">Vision</h2> <!--header 2 containing a class for CSS: Vision-->
    <p> <span style="color: rgb( 213 162 141);">TOWN</span> combines a variety of chinese cuisine to excite and delight our customers.
        Our vision for the future is to create experiential dining that is more than just a night out.<br> We aim to bring quality and luxury across all aspects of our brand.
        The approach of <span style="color: rgb( 213 162 141);">TOWN</span> is to develop our brand with the understanding of both our culture and consumer insights.<br> Within our vision always lives the promise of inspiring creativity, conversation and quality.
        Our audience is a high-end clientele who values a dining experience.<br>The age range of our customers are from early 30s-60s. We would like them to come back for both personal dining and events.
    </p>
</section>

<footer>
<div class="rectangle"> <!--This section is the footer-->
    &copy; 2022 ctowncuisine.com designed by <span>Mariah Mendoza</span>
</div>
</footer>

<script> src="./js/app.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and make a [mcve]

Comment: For example where do you execute your script? And where are the lines in the burger menu? (class="line1" etc)

Comment: Why did you set `li { opacity: 0 }`? It’s hiding all your navigation items…

Answer (score 0):

It‘s hard to help because your code does not work yet. The burger has no size so we cannot click it.

Otherwise, your positioning and transition seems fine. But you’re hiding all menu items with `opacity: 0`. Since the menu is white, you will not see anything.

The current code has some accessibility issues, meaning it does not work well with assistive technology, which people with disabilities rely on. I improved them and I’ll explain them further down.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.navigation');

  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (nav.classList.toggle('nav-active')) {
      // now it’s active
      burger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', true);
      nav.setAttribute('aria-hidden', false);
    } else {
      burger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', false);
      nav.setAttribute('aria-hidden', true);
    }
  });
}
const app = () => {
  navSlide();
}
```

```css
.navigation {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navigation a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .navigation {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .navigation {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: (white);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
  }
  .burger .line {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    height: .2em;
    margin: .4em 0;
  }
  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="townlogo">
    <!--Technically the header of the page, but used in the body for consistency-->
    <img src="Images/townlogo.jpg" alt="Town">
  </div>
  <button class="burger" id="burger" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navigation" onclick="navSlide()">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </button>
  <ul class="navigation" id="navigation">
    <!--section for top navigation bar-->
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="order_online.html">Order Online</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have posted my entire code just to show the full snippet of what I have going on. Not sure if this helps further. I just started an HTML and CSS class, so I am really new to this stuff, so my code is going to look pretty bad.

Comment: I also tried setting my code the same way you have fixed it. It ran, but the problem was that once it got into the mobile viewing, I couldn't click the burger to open the menu, and then as you made the view smaller you could see the slide function go from appearing to slide right to end up disappearing.